Flutter record package duplicate files
I am using the record package, when I try to background record on a timer every minute I get the same file, although the path to the file is different, but for some reason after decoding into base64 format I send the same file
I try deleting the previous files, canceling and restarting the recorder, but it doesn't help to solve the problem. What could be the reason for the repeating files
Here is are logs of my app:
I/flutter (13245): Background recording stopped. Output path: /storage/emulated/0/cloud_recorder/recordings/background_1728455699013.rn

I/flutter (13245): BACKGROUND base64: AAAAGGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAGlzb21tcDQyAAAMeGZyZWUwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA


I/flutter (13245): Background recording stopped. Output path: /storage/emulated/0/cloud_recorder/recordings/background_1728455575835.rn

I/flutter (13245): BACKGROUND base64: AAAAGGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAGlzb21tcDQyAAAMeGZyZWUwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA

Here is my code that returns the same file:
  AudioRecorder _backgroundRecorder =
      AudioRecorder(); 

  String? backgroundFilePath;

Future<void> startBackgroundRecording() async {
    try {
      await deleteOldBackgroundFiles();
      Directory appFolder = Directory(Paths.recording);
      bool appFolderExists = await appFolder.exists();
      if (!appFolderExists) {
        final created = await appFolder.create(recursive: true);
        print("Created recording folder: ${created.path}");
      }
      //
      final bgFilePath =
          '${Paths.recording}/background_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}${RecorderConstants.fileExtention}';
      backgroundFilePath = bgFilePath;

      final config = RecordConfig();
      await _backgroundRecorder.start(config, path: bgFilePath);
      print("BACKGROUND REC STARTED at $bgFilePath");
      _timer?.cancel();

      _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), (timer) async {
        if (await _backgroundRecorder.isRecording()) {
          await stopBackgroundRecording();
          await startBackgroundRecording();
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error starting background recording: $e');
    }
  }
  ///
  Future<void> stopBackgroundRecording() async {
    try {
      await _backgroundRecorder.stop().then((path) async {
        print('Background recording stopped. Output path: $path');
        File audioFile = File(path!);
        List<int> fileBytes = await audioFile.readAsBytes();
        print('FILE BYTES $fileBytes');
          String base64Audio = base64Encode(fileBytes);
          print('BACKGROUND base64: $base64Audio');
          print('BACKGROUND TIME: ${startTime + DateTime.now().toString()}');
          await RecorderRepo().record(
            file: base64Audio,
            session: session,
            startTime: startTime,
            endTime: DateTime.now().toString(),
          );
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error stopping background recording: $e');
    }
  }

